# C Program to convert binary numbers to Hex can't convert more than two binary numbers if they equal hex letters

Tags: c

For example if I type in 101010101010 it should equal AAA but it doesn't work. It only returns letters if it is less than two letters at a time. For example it works if I type in, "10101010". (It returns AA). Please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
void binary_hex(int n, char hex[]);
int hex_binary(char hex[]);

int main()
{
    printf("Enter binary number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    binary_hex(n,hex);
    printf("Hexadecimal number: %s",hex);
}

void binary_hex(int n, char hex[]) /* Function to convert binary to hexadecimal. */
{
    int i=0,decimal=0, rem;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        decimal += (n%10)*pow(2,i);
        n/=10;
        ++i;
    }

/* At this point, variable decimal contains binary number in decimal format. */
    i=0;
    while (decimal!=0)
    {
        rem=decimal%16;
        switch(rem)
        {
            case 10:
              hex[i]='A';
              break;
            case 11:
              hex[i]='B';
              break;
            case 12:
              hex[i]='C';
              break;
            case 13:
              hex[i]='D';
              break;
            case 14:
              hex[i]='E';
              break;
            case 15:
              hex[i]='F';
              break;
            default:
              hex[i]=rem+'0';
              break;
        }
        ++i;
        decimal/=16;
    }
    hex[i]='\0';
    strrev(hex);       /* Function to reverse string. */
}
```

Comment: Max-Value of int32 is `2147483647`. `2147483647`< `101010101010`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not shown a complete program - `n` is not declared in any scope in `main`.  Assuming `int n`, your first problem is here:

```
printf("Enter binary number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

You're reading the string of ones and zeros in as a base 10 (decimal) integer.  Instead, you should write a function that takes a `const char *` and iterates over each character, verifying it is either a 1 or 0, interpreting each one's value, and accumulating the total.  Hint: It may be easier to work in right to left order.

```
int parse_binary(const char *str)
{
    int total = 0;

    while (...) {
       total += ...
    }

    return total;
}
```

Another hint: Don't re-invent the wheel. Certainly, someone has wanted to parse binary numbers in C before you, no?  Check out `strtoul` - namely the description of its third parameter.

Note: Both things I've mentioned so far limit your binary values to 32 bits (or 64, depending on your data type choices).  If you don't need to actually use your integer values, any only convert a string of 1s and 0s to a string of hexadecimal values (of arbitrary length), then you can break up the problem into even simpler steps.

The reason we really like to use hexadecimal is that each character in a hex value represents exactly one *nibble*, which is exactly four bits.  That means every group of four 1s or 0s corresponds to exactly one hexadecimal character.  Assuming your input is always a multiple of 4 characters in length, you can easily process an arbitrarily long string.

```
D    E    A    D    B    E    E    F
1101 1110 1010 1101 1011 1110 1110 1111
```

Comment: Jonathon ,thank you, I am not very good at programming yet but I see what you are saying. I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

A very beginner friendly solution. This will work for big binary numbers/string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int hexConstant[] = {0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111};

    char hex[20000];
    char binary[20000];
    int index, i, digit;

    printf("Enter binary string: ");
    scanf("%s", binary);

    index = 0;
    int len = strlen(binary) ;
    for(int j =  len-1; j>=0; j-=4) {

         if(j-3>=0) digit = (binary[j-3]-'0')*1000 + (binary[j-2]-'0')*100 + (binary[j-1]-'0') * 10 + (binary[j]-'0');
         else if(j-3>=0) digit = (binary[j-2]-'0')*100 + (binary[j-1]-'0') * 10 + (binary[j]-'0');
         else if(j-1>=0) digit = (binary[j-1]-'0') * 10 + (binary[j]-'0');
         else digit = (binary[j]-'0');

         for(i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            if(hexConstant[i] == digit)
            {
                if(i<10)
                {
                    hex[index] = (char)(i + 48);
                }
                else
                {
                    hex[index] = (char)((i-10) + 65);
                }

                index++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    hex[index] = '\0';

    strrev(hex);

    printf("Hexadecimal number = %s", hex);

    return 0;
}
```